# Python pyplot colorbar and colormap have different colors

Tags: python, plot, graph, colorbar, colormap

I am currently trying to create a colormap. However, I have an issue whereby the colormap colors and the colorbar colors are different. How can I **change the colorbar color scheme** so that it matches the 'hot_r' colorscheme of the map?

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

x_list = np.array(X_COORDINATE)
z_list = np.array(Z_COORDINATE)
C_I_list = np.array(C_I)

# f will be a function with two arguments (x and z coordinates),
# but those can be array_like structures too, in which case the
# result will be a matrix representing the values in the grid 
# specified by those arguments
f = interp2d(x_list,z_list,C_I_list,kind="linear")

x_coords = np.arange(min(x_list),max(x_list)+1)
z_coords = np.arange(min(z_list),max(z_list)+1)
c_i = f(x_coords,z_coords)

fig = plt.imshow(c_i,
           extent=[min(x_list),max(x_list),min(z_list),max(z_list)],
           origin="lower", interpolation='spline16', cmap='hot_r')

x_for_horizontal_line = [0,1]
y_for_horizontal_line = [1,1]

x_for_vertical_line = [1,1]
y_for_vertical_line = [0,1]


# Show the positions of the sample points, just to have some reference
fig.axes.set_autoscale_on(False)
plt.scatter(x_list,z_list,400,facecolors='none')
plt.plot(x_for_horizontal_line, y_for_horizontal_line, color='w')
plt.plot(x_for_vertical_line, y_for_vertical_line, color='w')
plt.xlim(left=1,right=5)
plt.xlabel('NF Fracture Center, x (m)')
plt.ylabel('NF Fracture Center, z (m)')
plt.title('C I')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The resulting map and colorbar looks as follows (note I cannot show the actual data hence the weirdly cropped image):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBuzQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this was a simple mistake. I hadn't called 'fig' in the colorbar() arguments.

Therefore, for others' interest, replacing the second to last line of code with :

```
plt.colorbar(fig)
```

does the job.

Comment: `fig = plt.imshow(...)` is an extremely confusing name for the variable. `fig` is normally used for the figure (the surrounding figure which holds all subplots). Please avoid using that name for something else. Better use something like `img = plt.imshow()`